# Как в JavaScript заменить символ на рисунок?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте!

Имеются таблицы `one.csv, two.csv`.

содержание таблиц таково:
4

```
326;8808;567; 11/12/2013;00:00    
0;c0;-30000;r0;5.1;93  
1;c1;-30000;r1;5.5;93  
3;c2;268;r3;5.1;93  
5;c3;-30000;r2;5.1;93 
6;c3;-30000;s2;5.1;93
```

и т.д

как заменить `с0,c1,c2,c3,r0,r1,r3` на рисунки и вставить на `html` страницу в виде таблицы добавив заголовки?

вот так оно должно выглядеть

```
11/12/2013|00:00   
парам1.....|парам2...|парам3..|парам4....|парам5.....|парам6....|  
0..........|рис1.....|-30000..|рис2......|5.1........|93........|  
1..........|рис3.....|-30000..|рис4......|5.5........|93........|  
3..........|рис5.....|268.....|рис6......|5.1........|93........|
```

и т.д.

Comment: Решил проблему с помощью php, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var reg = /[cr0-9]+/i;

        for(var i=0;i<td.length;i++){

            if(reg.test(td[i].innerHTML)){
                td[i].innerHTML = "рисуночки, картиночки";
            }

        }
```

Comment: спасибо большое, я в первый раз не корректно задал вопрос.

Comment: у меня что-то не получилось